# Copying files with specific size to other directory

Tags: shell, unix

Its a interview question. Interviewer asked this "basic" shell script question when he understand i don't have experience in shell scripting. Here is question.

Copy files from one directory which has size greater than 500 K to another directory.

I can do it immediately in c lang but seems difficult in shell script as never tried it.I am familiar with unix basic commands so i tried it, but i can just able to extract those file names using below command.

```
du -sk * | awk  '{ if ($1>500) print $2 }'
```

Also,Let me know good shell script examples book.

Comment: Other than using `du *` instead of `du dir`, this is a reasonable solution, but `find` is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` recurses into subdirectories, which is probably not desired (you could have asked for clarification if that point was ambiguous). More likely you were expected to use `ls -l` or `ls -s` to get the sizes.

But what you did works to select some files and print their names, so let's build on it. You have a command that outputs a list of names. You need to put the output of that command into the command line of a `cp`. If your du|awk outputs this:

```
Makefile
foo.c
bar.h
```

you want to run this:

```
cp Makefile foo.c bar.h otherdirectory
```

So how you do that is with ***COMMAND SUBSTITUTION*** which is written as `$(...)` like this:

```
cd firstdirectory
cp $(du -sk * | awk '{ if ($1>500) print $2 }') otherdirectory
```

And that's a functioning script. The du|awk command runs first, and its output is used to build the cp command. There are a lot of subtle drawbacks that would make it unsuitable for general use, but that's how beginner-level shell scripts usually are.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in several ways. I'd try and use find:

```
find $FIRSTDIRECTORY -size +500k -exec cp "{\} $SECONDDIRECTORY \;
```

To limit to the current directory, use -maxdepth option.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +BYTESc -exec cp -t DESTDIR {}\+
```

The `c` suffix on the size is essential; the size is in bytes.   Otherwise, you get probably-unexpected rounding behaviour in determining the result of the `-size` check.   If the copying is meant to be recursive, you will need to take care of creating any destination directory also.